# General tips for starting a master's thesis

Tags: graduate-school, masters

In September I'll be starting my second year in my master's in which I'm writing my master's thesis. I have everything set up and I am starting to go through some of the literature during the summer.

As this is my first 'larger' project I am involved with, I wanted to ask for some tips on how to handle and structure a thesis, or larger research projects in general. I want to implement some good practices when starting my thesis and try to avoid common mistakes made by grad students.

I'm open for any kind of answers, from personal anecdotes and 'lessons learned' to e.g. software for organizing ideas like Obsidian.

Answer (score 2):

Document everything! OK, this might depend a bit on what kind of work you are doing, but for me as a lab rat that is one of the most important things. Once you sit down to write your thesis it makes such a difference if you have good structured notes to go back and remind yourself of exactly what experiment you did and when/how, what observations you made, what conclusions you drew, etc. This is important even for experiments that didn't work.

Also in a really big project it is really easy to get lost and feel like you don't really know what goal it is you are actually working to. It will take some time for you to wrap your head around everything, so try to break it up into smaller problems. This is also where your supervisor's guidance can be really important. I have sometimes made the mistake of not asking my supervisor for help when I've been stuck and they could have given me a push in the right direction. Better to ask one too many times than one too few :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm keeping some kind of log already of what I'm doing, and I'm trying to create a general structure in my note-taking.  I'll keep in mind what you mentioned about breaking everything up into smaller problems. That'll help with the digestion of large amounts of material.

Answer (score 0):

The best time to start organising ideas and taking note is from the first year. The second best time is ***now***. So, you're still *good* to go.

In your writing up, have/develop a story line. Your literature, methodology, findings/results and discussion all end up fitting into your narrative (story line); not just discussion.

For your literature, annotation and referencing, you can't go wrong with [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/). I actually moved away from Mendeley to Zotero due to Mendeley *encrypting* their SQLite db.
If your institution offers [Endnote](https://endnote.com/), feel free to use as alternative to Zotero.

I'm aware you mentioned master's thesis. Tips for PhD writing will equally be important.

Andy Stapleton provide [guidance for writing thesis](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMgdrrbOPUKNNQQITqJEAFAXMhzfHdgpB) and good ol' [tools/tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrC2vS9j30g&list=PLMgdrrbOPUKNZzz4qg3g08FPmqTQKrdQQ&index=13&t=82s).

Just to mention that most universities have good resources for writing up. Check with your university's writing center and postgraduate center/school.

---

Martin Adams has a *comprehensive* [tour of Obsidian for PHD Students](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XE_CGBlQ17o)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear, but the thesis in my case only starts in the second year. So in that sense I am a bit early by starting in the summer. I'm generally also interested in stuff like keeping a log, that aren't necessarily fully connected to the writing of the thesis itself. In any case, thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're on track and being proactive enough. The *actual* writing up will be iterative. Starting now on thoughts, approach, tools including structured log taking and literature mgt would go a long way.

Comment: When the *writing* gets full gear, your structured logs and literature will be invaluable ... "*I'm generally also interested in stuff like keeping a log, that aren't necessarily fully connected to the writing of the thesis itself*"

Comment: Do you have any concrete tips on how/what to log? For now I'm just keeping track of what I read with some comments on the content.